# Android HTML5 example needed

Tags: android, html

I have tried to implement HTML5 in Android OS. But i didnt get it....Can anyone give example  HTML 5 in Android?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "HTML5"?

Comment: Show us source code that you tried to make work.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could provide more detail than "I didn't get it."

Answer (score 10):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>I'm Batman</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Load [this example](http://www.html5laboratory.com/s/geolocation-api-example.html) on your Android phone. It's in HTML5, written by me, and will show you your location on a Google Map (if you let it of course).

Works fine on my HTC Desire.

Answer (score 3):

I've got a repository up for HTML5 examples on github.
Android uses the "defacto standards" that apple has set forth for some features (such as App icon).

http://coolaj86.github.com/iphone-html5-offline-app-demo

https://github.com/coolaj86/iphone-html5-offline-app-demo

I'd be happy to add any simple demos you find or look up more specific info.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Sencha Touch demos here http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/demos.php, which contains some awesome web applications based on HTML5.